# \halign does not affect \prevdepth?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tex-core

What is the purpose of restoring the initial value of `\prevdepth` at the end of a horizontal alignment:

```
\prevdepth=.1234pt
\everycr{\noalign{\dimen0=\prevdepth prevdepth in noalign: \the\dimen0}}
\halign{%
\strut #\strut%
\cr
Text in a horizontal alignment%
\cr}
\dimen0=\prevdepth prevdepth after horizonal alignment: \the\dimen0
\bye
```

[image]

EDIT:

Above output was produced by LuaTeX version beta-0.79.1.

Comment: think of this more generally -- the argument of `\halign` is a local group.  all temporary settings are abandoned when a group is closed.  if a setting needs to be preserved after the group is closed, it must intentionally be set globally.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The TeXbook, p. 282: “The value of \prevdepth at the time of the `\halign` is used at the beginning of the internal vertical list, and the final value of `\prevdepth` is carried to the enclosing vertical list when the alignment is completed, so that the interline glue is calculated properly at the beginning and end of the alignment.” Indeed, the value shown when TeX is used (as opposed to LuaTeX) is 1.9444pt (the same with XeTeX).

Comment: @egreg -- okay.  so this is a bug only in luatex.  thanks.  (guess i have to go back to reading the basics ... in my voluminous free time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the engine that has been reported [here](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=723) and will be fixed in the next release.